# cleardot.gif issue with section 508

Tags: html, accessibility

I have an application that we wanna get Section 508 certificate on it. 
we have some google staff there that contain this tag on it

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/cleardot.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

and the auditor says Add an alt attribute to your img element.

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a spacer image, so ideally: Replace it with CSS margins or padding.

Failing that, add an alt attribute that explicitly says it is equivalent to no content:

```
alt=""
```

See [Alan Flavell's writings on the subject](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html) for more information on choosing good alt text (and the section marked *a) "Page decorations"* for this specific case).

Comment: how can I add alt attribute by css??

Comment: @Amir — CSS is for presentation, not content. You need to add the attribute to the HTML.

Comment: @Quentin the problem is I can't add attribute manually because it's creating on fly.it's part of google staff plug in like translation. I want to find a way to override it

Comment: so write a script (jQuery is easiest) that waits to detect the image in the dom, the add  the attribute, although i bet that this will not work amazingly across various user agents

Answer (score 0):

If it's truly a spacer, then the screen reader user doesn't need to know about it and you can use `role='presentation'`

```
<img role="presentation" src="https://www.google.com/images/cleardot.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

But that might have the same problem as the previous solution if you're looking for a CSS way to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

It's a ["web bug" (or "tracking beacon")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug), You could hide the image (from screenreaders too) by using an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation):

```css
img[src="https://www.google.com/images/cleardot.gif"] {
  display: none;
}
```

But that might violate the google's terms of use of the service.